# solving equations and finding values of x and y from two equations in c programming

Tags: c

Is solving equations possible in c programming using math library?

If I have two equations

```
 y-y1=m1(x-x1)
```

and

```
y-y2=m2(x-x2)
```

I'll be generating the values of `m1`, `m2`, `x1`, `x2`,`y1`, `y2` through the fomrula in the program. Will I be able to find the value of `x` and `y`? I tried, but I couldn't.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. Please be aware that we do not provide _from-scratch_ coding service here. :-)

Comment: Please show us what you've tried , how it failed and we might be able to help.

Comment: You need to solve the 2 equations as simultaneous equations to get the formulae for x and y in terms of the other values. then you can implement those equations in code to calculate x and y.

Comment: You probably want to read [line-line intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#Given_the_equations_of_the_lines) and derive the formula from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If m1, m2, x1, x2, y1, y2 are known then using this formulae you can find them

X = [(2*y1)/(m2-m1)] - [(2*m1*x1)/(m2-m1)] + [(m1*x1)/(m2-m1)] + [(m2*x2)/(m2-m1)] + [(y1+y2)/(m2-m1)]

and for y:

Y = [(y1+y2)/2] + [(m1+m2)***X**/2] - [(m1*x1)/2] - [(m2*x2)/2]

Note: In the formula for Y appears X, but if you compute it before it is not a problem